# c# Account Expiration Date with dateTimePiker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I would like to set `principal.AccountExpirationDate` with a `dateTimePicker1`

if i do this - its work:

```
principal.AccountExpirationDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12);
```

but when i try to use the dateTimePicker1 its not work - this is my code:

```
string enddate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy, MM, dd");
 int val = Convert.ToInt32(enddate);
principal.AccountExpirationDate = new DateTime(val);
```

Im getting error.

how can i covert the dateTimePicker1 to a value that i can set in the principal.AccountExpirationDate?

Comment: Why do you convert `string` representation of your `DateTime` to `int`? That does not make sense. And it will never be a valid integer. Why not just do `principal.AccountExpirationDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;`?

Comment: [Im getting error](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/)

Comment: Because date time picker value is a STRING and to set an account expiration date i should use an INT.

Comment: not so, a `DateTimePicker.Value` is a `DateTime` type; yours is string because you used `.ToString()`  see [DateTimePicker.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks - I realized my mistake.  principal.AccountExpirationDate = dateTimePicker1.Value; thats it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert `DateTime` or `DateTime formated string` to `integer` but you can take `dateTime.Day`, `dateTime.Month` or `dateTime.Year` as an `integer` separately.

```
int val = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
int month = dateTimePicker1.Value.Month; 
int year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;
principal.AccountExpirationDate = new DateTime(year, month, val);
```

But `principal.AccountExpirationDate = dateTimePicker1.Value` is better one because `dateTimePicker1.Value` returns `DateTime`

Comment: No, no, no. This does not make sense. This will create a DateTime just added `val` ticks to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: The problem is that the date time picker is a STRING. i should convert it to an int